# Free fall equations

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, free-fall

I've been looking for this on the internet for a long time, but nowhere explains it clearly, and I need to explicitly calculate this and not other things:
If I have the height at which an object is, and it falls, how do I calculate at what speed and at what height it will be at x time?

Comment: Have you tried to google free fall equation?

Comment: Yes, but I can't understand.

Comment: There isn't an equation that says how to calculate the speed of an object falling then of x seconds

Comment: There is even an explicit calculator https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/free-fall. Make an effort to understand that and tell us what exactly what it is you don’t understand.

Comment: @NicolásCastellanos, is air drag involved?

Comment: @DavidWhite No, free fall

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_fall

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the object starts falling from rest at height $h$, then its velocity at time $t$ later is

$$\vec v=-gt\hat z$$

and its vertical position is

$$z=h-\frac12gt^2$$

where $g$ is the magnitude of the constant and uniform downward gravitational acceleration. This neglects air drag, and assumes that the gravitational field is the same everywhere.

These equations come from integrating the kinematical equation for free-fall,

$$a_z=\frac{d^2z}{dt^2}=-g,$$

and applying the initial conditions that $z=h$ and $\vec v=0$ at $t=0$.

Comment: I have another question. In the height equation, what's the "z"?

Comment: $z$ is the vertical coordinate at time $t$, which is the height at time $t$. Cartesian coordinates are usually called $x,y,z$. In 2D problems people often use $x$ for horizontal and $y$ for vertical but in 3D problems you need both $x$ and $y$ for horizontal so $z$ is vertical.